# Why setState() doesn't update render on React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to make a 2D game-board that consists of "Cells" which has a binary state value called `isAlive`. The user can change this value by clicking on them. This value is indicated to the user using different colors. The `Board.js` constructor creates every cell with a `false` value.
The board also has a "Reset" button to reset all Cell's back to `false`.

The values of the Cells changes correctly when I click on them. When "Reset" button is clicked, I want every Cell's `isAlive` value to be `false`. However, when "Reset" button is pressed visually there is no change on the board (The Cell's colors doesn't change). The `console.log(this.state.cells);` line on  `handleClick()` method on `Board.js` prints `props: Object { isAlive: false }` for all Cells. So why the Cell's are not updating visually? What am I doing wrong here?

Board.js

```
export default class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cells: []
        };
        this.rowNum = 10;
        this.colNum = 10;

        for (let i = 0; i < (this.rowNum * this.colNum); i++) {
            this.state.cells.push(<Cell isAlive={false}/>);
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.getCols = this.getCols.bind(this);

    }

    getCols() {
        let cols = [];
        for (let i = this.rowNum; i <= (this.rowNum * this.colNum); i += this.rowNum) {
            cols.push(this.state.cells.slice(i - this.rowNum, i).map(function (item, i) {
                return <div key={i}>{item}</div>
            }));
        }
        return cols;
    }

    handleClick() {
        const newBoard = this.state.cells;
        newBoard.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
            arr[index] = <Cell isAlive={false}/>
        });
        this.setState({
                cells: newBoard
            }, function () {
                console.log(this.state.cells);
            }
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (<div className="background">
                <table className="gameBoard">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {this.getCols().map(function (item, index) {
                            return <td className="col" key={index}>{item}</td>
                        })}
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Reset</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

The significant parts of the Cell.js:

```
export default class Cell extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.colors = {
            dead: '#041b40',
            alive: '#b2e8f7',
            hover_dead: '#495d76',
            hover_alive: '#e6fffd'
        };

        this.state = {
            isAlive: this.props.isAlive,
            isMouseDown: false,
            isHovering: false
        };


        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            isAlive: !this.state.isAlive,
            isMouseDown: this.state.isMouseDown,
            isHovering: this.state.isHovering

        })
    }

    ...

    determineColor() {
        if (this.state.isAlive && this.state.isHovering) {
            return this.colors.hover_alive;
        } else if (!this.state.isAlive && this.state.isHovering) {
            return this.colors.hover_dead;
        } else if (this.state.isAlive && !this.state.isHovering) {
            return this.colors.alive;
        }else {
            return this.colors.dead;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className='square'
                        onClick={this.handleClick}
                        type='button'
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: this.determineColor()
                        }}>
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    };


}
```

Comment: You don't need to preserve Cell components as a state of Board component. You should preserve only the alive state of cells in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the inner state on props change:

```js
export default class Cell extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.colors = {
            dead: '#041b40',
            alive: '#b2e8f7',
            hover_dead: '#495d76',
            hover_alive: '#e6fffd'
        };

        this.state = {
            isAlive: this.props.isAlive,
            isMouseDown: false,
            isHovering: false
        };


        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { //<--HERE
       this.setState({isAlive: this.props.isAlive})
    }
    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            isAlive: !this.state.isAlive,
            isMouseDown: this.state.isMouseDown,
            isHovering: this.state.isHovering

        })
    }

    ...

    determineColor() {
        if (this.state.isAlive && this.state.isHovering) {
            return this.colors.hover_alive;
        } else if (!this.state.isAlive && this.state.isHovering) {
            return this.colors.hover_dead;
        } else if (this.state.isAlive && !this.state.isHovering) {
            return this.colors.alive;
        }else {
            return this.colors.dead;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className='square'
                        onClick={this.handleClick}
                        type='button'
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: this.determineColor()
                        }}>
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Both your and zahra's answers works fine when I click the button for the first time. However, when I click the button for the second time, it doesn't visually update again. Why is that?

Comment: your click function always set to false, so why would any change happen?

Comment: I changed some of the of Cell's isAlive value to "true" by clicking on them before resetting for the second time. Those Cells still stayed "true" after pressing the reset button.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you to change the state to true and false https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

You must use the componentDidUpdate

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    
      if (this.props.isAlive!== prevProps.isAlive) {
      this.setState({isAlive: this.props.isAlive})
      }
    }
```